# pymongo to RMongo, mongodb sort query

Tags: mongodb, sorting, pymongo, rmongo

In pymongo I'm doing a sort query like this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
dbase = client[dbname]
collection = dbase[symbol]
start = time.time()
cursor = collection.find().sort([{'_id', -1}]).limit(6000)
data = list(cursor)
```

Trying to do the same thing in R now...

```
library("RMongo")
mongo <- mongoDbConnect("dbname", "localhost", 27017) 
query = '{sort({_id: -1})}'
output <- dbGetQuery(mongo, "symbol", query, skip=0, limit=6000)

> output
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

what is the proper JSON query string format here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out with mongolite....

```
library('mongolite')
con <- mongo("collection_name", url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname")
output <- con$find('{}', sort='{"_id":-1}', limit=6000)
```